# Converting llvm bitcode library to a native code library

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm

**Background:**
I have quite a few dynamic frameworks that are built with bitcode support. Because of a couple of other dependencies I am unable to support bitcode on my main application, and since I'm working on an iOS application, builds get rejected when I send them to iTunes Connect for distribution because they contain frameworks with bitcode in them. So regardless of the reasons why they are doing this, I need to remove bitcode from the frameworks in order to distrubute my application.

**Question:** 
Is there a way to convert bitcode binaries to native binaries via one of the llvm, clang or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a way which avoids going from bitcode to IR, but the following chain works at least:

```
clang -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc #Source  -> Bitcode
llvm-dis hello.bc -o hello.ll               #Bitcode -> IR
clang hello.ll -o hello                     #IR      -> Native
```

Comment: That requires recompilation of the source though. Would it be possible to convert the already compiled library, a .dylib in this case?

Comment: I haven't worked with .dylib files, so I don't know any details regarding it. I guess it is not possible to run llvm-dis on it?

Comment: Actually I was looking at the example from my phone and slightly misinterpreted it, I'll try it out a bit later.